# PHP - str_replace multiple symbols

Tags: php

I have the following string "Il-kelb ta Mariia jismu il-Bobo"

Users usually enter the sentence above. Sometimes they enter the sentence as

```
"Il-kelb ta Mariia jismu il--Bobo" - i.e. double dashes OR
"Il---kelb ta Mariia jismu il---Bobo" - i.e. double dashes; or 
"Il-----------------------kelb ta Mariia jismu il-------Bobo" - i.e. double dashes; or
```

I usually use str_replace e.g. `str_replace('--','-')`
If its three dashes its `str_replace('---','-')`
If its four dashes its `str_replace('----','-')`

In certain instances it will echo -- or --- regardless

I would like to know how to make a function not to allow two dashes next to each other, otherwise the `str_replace('----','-')` will go for unlimited combinations.

I would like to output one dash if they are next to each other.

Comment: you could replace two dashes with one in an iteration until no change is made to the string..

Answer (score 4):

Use `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace("/-{2,}/", "-", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a simple `while` loop this way:

```
while (strpos($string, "--") !== false)
  $string = str_replace("--", "-", $string);
```

Or if you are planning to use regular expressions, you can do this way:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\-+/", "-", $string);
```

Comment: I'm not sure (that's why I removed the down vote), but won't the while loop only work if there is an even number of `-`?

Comment: Nopes. It goes through an iteration. You an check for yourself. So, if there are `---` in a string, it makes it `--` and in the next iteration, it makes it `-`. Check it out.